# I'm stuck with a prime number calculator

Tags: python, math, logic, primes

I'm reading a book about python programming for begginers.
One of it's tasks is to write a prime number calcutator that calculates 'n' prime numbers.
So far I've studied strings, logic gates, while and conditions.

The idea is to make it using only those operators.

I need help because I'm stuck with this code.

Here's what I've done:

```
odd = 3
number = 2
limit = int(input('How many primes do you need: '))
remnant = number % odd
even_remnant = number % 2
counter = 0

while counter <= limit:
    if number == 2:
        print('2')
        number += 2
    elif (number % 2) != 0:
        remnant = number % odd
        while odd < number:
            print('while2')
            remnant = number % odd
            if (number % odd) != 0 and odd == (number - 1):
                print(f'{number}.')
                odd = 3
                number += 1
                counter += 1
                break
            elif (number % odd) == 0:
                break
            odd += 2
    elif (number % 2) == 0:
        number += 1
        odd = 3
```

What do you think?

Thanks everyone.

Comment: Just from cursory reading I can see two variables that are never defined, `counter` and `impar`. You also have variables that are defined but never used, `remnant` and `even_remnant`. I can almost understand what you're trying to do, but not quite. I think you should back away from the keyboard and write down the algorithm(s) you are using and an explanation of why you think the algorithm(s) will succeed. Also, in python the `for` loop is pretty fundamental, in particular the `for` looping over a sequence of integers specified by the `range` "function". You should learn it for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your debugging pants on, we're going in.

First, the code doesn't run as it's written. The variables `counter` and `impar` are undefined. First step is to remove syntax errors like that. Looks like we want to start counter at 0 and the line that uses impar isn't necessary so we can delete it.

```
odd = 3
number = 2
limit = int(input('How many primes do you need: '))

counter = 0
while counter < limit:
    if number == 2:
        print('2')
        number += 2
    elif (number % 2) != 0:
        while odd < number:
            print('while2')
            remnant = number % odd
            if (number % odd) != 0 and odd == (number - 1):
                print(f'{number}.')
                odd = 3
                number += 1
                break
            elif (number % odd) == 0:
                break
            odd += 2
    elif (number % 2) == 0:
        number += 1
        odd = 3
```

Now the code runs without error, but all it does is print

```
2
while2
```

And then fails to terminate.

So we know we enter the `while odd < number` loop only once and we don't print anything during that loop. If we also print the value of `odd` and `number` while we are in there we see `odd = 3` and `number = 5`. Neither of the if conditions are met and the `odd += 2` line is hit. Now `odd = 5` and the while loop exits without printing 5 even though 5 is prime. If we want to hit our print statement by meeting the condition `odd == (number - 1)` we better go in steps of 1 when incrementing `odd`. Let's change to `odd += 1` and re-run the code.

Now when I say I need 2 primes it prints

```
2
5
7
```

And then prints `while2` forever. At least it prints prime numbers! But it skipped 3 and printed too many, and I had to use Ctrl-C to quit the program. Too many primes were printed because the outer loop `while counter <= limit:` condition was never reached. Inside the loop, we never increase the value of counter. Whenever we print a prime, we need to increase counter.

Also, to make sure we print 3, take a look at the first if condition in the loop.

```
if number == 2:
    print('2')
    number += 2  # Oops, we skipped over 3
```

Let's update this:

```
if number == 2:
    print('2')
    print('3')
    counter += 2 # Let's count both of these!
    number += 2
```

Also adding `counter += 1` after the other print, re-running the code we get

```
How many primes do you need: 2
2
3
5.

How many primes do you need: 3
2
3
5.
7.
```

Oops, we are getting one more than we need. This is because when `counter == limit` we run the while loop one more time. Let's change our while loop condition to `while counter < limit:`. That change gets us just the right number of primes.

```
How many primes do you need: 4
2
3
5.
7.
```

But if we ask for 5

```
How many primes do you need: 5
2
3
5.
7.
```

And the program never exits. If we check the values of odd and number, we see that the loops is running with `odd=3` and `number=9` over and over again.

Reason through the code when odd=3 and number=9. We break out of the `while odd < number` while loop when we hit this code

```
elif (number % odd) == 0
    break
```

But we never increase the value of number, so it is still equal to 9 the next time through the loop. Let's update this to

```
elif (number % odd) == 0
    number += 1
    break
```

Now when we re-run the code we get

```
How many primes do you need: 5
2
3
5.
7.
11.
```

Huzzah! And it works when asking for more primes as well. Here is the code as it is currently:

```
odd = 3
number = 2
limit = int(input('How many primes do you need: '))

counter = 0
while counter < limit:
    if number == 2:
        print('2')
        print('3')
        counter += 2
        number += 2
    elif (number % 2) != 0:
        while odd < number:
            if (number % odd) != 0 and odd == (number - 1):
                print(f'{number}.')
                odd = 3
                number += 1
                break
            elif (number % odd) == 0:
                number += 1
                break
            odd += 1
    elif (number % 2) == 0:
        number += 1
        odd = 3
```

Now that we have working code, let's improve it! One of our bugs was that we forgot to increase number by 1 in one case. Notice that no matter how we exit the outer while loop `while counter <= limit:` we want to increment number. So, instead of doing it in many places, let's move all of those to the end of the while block.

We also set odd=3 whenever exiting the while block. What we want to ensure is that odd=3 at the start of the while loop, so let's move that there. Now there is no more code in the `elif (number % 2) == 0:` block, so we can remove that line.

```
number = 2
limit = int(input('How many primes do you need: '))

counter = 0
while counter < limit:
    odd = 3
    if number == 2:
        print('2')
        print('3')
        counter += 2
    elif (number % 2) != 0:
        while odd < number:
            if (number % odd) != 0 and odd == (number - 1):
                print(f'{number}.')
                counter += 1
                break
            elif (number % odd) == 0:
                break
            odd += 1

    number += 1
```

I think the code is more clear if the while loop ends when the condition is met, rather than on break statements. We want the while loop to end if we find the number is divisible by something, or we run out of numbers to check.

```
`while number % odd != 0 and odd < number:`
```

And the only thing we need to do in the while loop is increment odd. Then after the loop, we can check the value of odd to see which condition was met.

```
number = 2
limit = int(input('How many primes do you need: '))

counter = 0
while counter < limit:
    odd = 3
    if number == 2:
        print('2')
        print('3')
        counter += 2
    elif (number % 2) != 0:
        while number % odd != 0 and odd < number:
            odd += 1
        if odd == number: # No divisor was found!
            print(f'{number}.')
            counter += 1

    number += 1
```

Notice that we are "hard coding" the divisibility by 2 `(number % 2) != 0` and then using the variable `odd` to check divisibility by everything else. If we start odd at 2 instead of 3, we don't have to do the hard coding.

```
number = 2
limit = int(input('How many primes do you need: '))

counter = 0
while counter < limit:
    odd = 2
    if number == 2:
        print('2')
        print('3')
        counter += 2
    while number % odd != 0 and odd < number:
        odd += 1
    if odd == number: # No divisor was found!
        print(f'{number}.')
        counter += 1

    number += 1
```

When we make this change, we also notice that we find the primes 2 and 3 twice, so we can remove the hard coded version of those:

```
number = 2
limit = int(input('How many primes do you need: '))

counter = 0
while counter < limit:
    odd = 2
    while number % odd != 0 and odd < number:
        odd += 1
    if odd == number: # No divisor was found!
        print(f'{number}.')
        counter += 1

    number += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

When I try to run this code it tells me that Counter is not set, so right before entering the loop set Counter to 0.

Another problem is that you start by finding 2 in the first case of your loop, this is nice. Here after the loop runs again, now with number set to 4. Because of your += 2 instruction.

It then runs the last elif case. where (number % 2) == 0. here it set number = 5, and odd = 3. But it doesn't print 3. I think you mean to do this.

Now it runs the loop again, and enter the second elif case (number % 2) != 0.
The first line in the elif clause the variable impar is not defined so it will fail.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I can't understand your program but it's good

```
def is_prime(n):
    st = "prime" #  being prime status

    for i in range(2,n):
        if n % i == 0: # if number is prime
            st = "not prime"
            break;


    return st 



n = int(input("enter n:  ")) 

pc = 0 # prime conter
c = 1 # counter


while n != pc:
    if is_prime(c) == "prime":
        print (c)
        pc += 1
    c += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

To calculate 'n' number for prime numbers you needn't use so many statements, if you make use of the the **arithmetic** and **logical** or **bit-wise** operators, which you will be learning in the future chapters of the python book you're referring.
I shall help you by editing the code for you.

```py
    number = int(input("Enter range: "))
    print("Prime numbers:", end=' ')
    for n in range(2, number):
        for i in range(2, n):
            if n % i == 0:
                break
        else:
        print(n, end=' ')
```

Comment: I haven't made use of the logical and bit-wise operators here, the %(modulus) function gives the reminder of a division operation. Hence you can make it like a simple program.